# Coroutine job completing even after cancellation from external function

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have this function:

```
suspend fun functionCall(): Job {
      return MainScope().launch {
       var i = 0
       while(i < 3) {
         i++
         delay(3000)
         yield()
      }
     }
    cancel()
}
```

And I am calling from an external function when a button is clicked:

```
MainScope().launch {
   if(functionCall().isActive) {
      functionCall().cancelAndJoin()
   }
}
```

Both of these functions are being run in a repository class.
And it is still iterating through the whole while loop even after the above if statement is triggered. What I'm noticing while debugging is "i" is also being reset to 0 which could indicate the job is being triggered more than once but it is definitely being triggered only once so I'm confused about what is happening.

What I want to happen is after that if statement for the entire job to cancel and for the entire function to return and run no more code.

I've also tried while(ensureActive) and the same thing is happening.

How do I do this?

Comment: For every `functionCall()` , it creates new Job, so that's why one of jobs still continue to do the work.

Comment: By launching your inner job from a new coroutine scope, it is not a child job of the coroutine that calls `functionCall()`. It is completely independent. You should not be creating a new `MainScope()` to use inside your suspend function unless you explicitly want it to be a separate coroutine with no manageable lifecycle or relation to the coroutine that calls this function.

Comment: It is generally a code smell to use `MainScope().launch` or `CoroutineScope().launch` because there's no point in creating a new CoroutineScope if you aren't going to reference it anywhere so you can manage its lifecycle. You might as well use GlobalScope then.

Comment: @AliBabadi What should I do to prevent this? Should I assign functionCall to a variable and then run the 2 'isActive' and 'cancelAndJoin()' ?

Comment: It's hard to say what you should do because it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish by launching a job and then immediately cancelling it.

Comment: @tenfour04 I am wanting to completely cancel the coroutine if a button is clicked. The button triggers that if statement to call. Inside of the coroutine is a block of code that retries a service connection but if the button is clicked cancels the entire thing.

Comment: @tenfour04 Would really appreciate if you have any suggestions as I'm not very familiar with coroutines :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is Android, you should launch your UI-related coroutines from `lifecycleScope`. If you have a job that needs to survive screen rotations, you should launch it from inside a ViewModel from `viewModelScope`, and it must not touch any UI elements.

If you want to cancel a specific coroutine when an event happens, you should store that coroutine Job in a property so you can call `cancel()` on it. So a typical pattern inside an Activity for example might be:

```
private var fooJob: Job? = null

private fun fooSomething() {
    fooJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeat(5) {
            delay(1000)
            Log.i("count", it.toString())
        }
    }
}

private fun cancelCurrentFoo() {
    fooJob?.cancel()
}
```

Suppose you have a coroutine job you can start by calling one of the functions of your ViewModel, but you want the Activity/Fragment to be able to cancel it early. Then you expose a function that returns the coroutine Job:

```
fun foo() = viewModelScope.launch {
    repeat(5) {
        delay(1000)
        Log.i("count", it.toString())
    }
}
```

The Activity can call this function and it gets a Job instance in return that it can call `cancel()` on whenever it wants.

Comment: Awesome, I tried this approach and things are working now. You're awesome! Thanks!